# How to make separate if statements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I'm trying to write a program that takes an integer, seconds, as an input and returns it as, n years, n days, n hours, n minutes and n seconds.(n could be different for each)

But for some reason it doesn't go in the second if statement. I've put print("x") to test if it goes in the if statement, but the program only prints out one "x", which is in the first if statement, and it doesn't go in the other ones.

I've been trying to figure out why it does that, but I can't seem to do it. I've also looked up some stuff on the internet, so that I wouldn't bother someone with a question that has a reasonably easy answer, but I couldn't find anything.

Here is my code:

```
def format_duration(seconds):
    decimal_list = []

    second_decimal = seconds % 60
    seconds -= second_decimal
    seconds /= 60

    decimal_list.append(int(second_decimal))

    if seconds >= 60:
        minute_decimal = seconds % 60
        seconds -= minute_decimal
        seconds /= 60

        decimal_list.append(int(minute_decimal))
        print("x")

        if minute_decimal > 1:
            minute_txt = "minutes"
    
        else:
            minute_txt = "minute"

    if seconds >= 3600:
        hour_decimal = seconds % 24
        seconds -= hour_decimal
        seconds /= 24

        decimal_list.append(int(hour_decimal))
        print("x")

        if hour_decimal > 1:
            hour_txt = "hours"
            
        else:
            hour_txt = "hour"

    if seconds >= 86400:
        day_decimal = seconds % 365
        seconds -= day_decimal
        seconds /= 365

        decimal_list.append(int(day_decimal))
        print("x")

        if day_decimal > 1:
            day_txt = "days"
                
        else:
            day_txt = "day"

    if seconds >= 31536000:
        year_decimal = seconds

        decimal_list.append(int(year_decimal))
        print("x")

        if year_decimal > 1:
            year_txt = "years"
                    
        else:
            year_txt = "year"

    for i in range(len(decimal_list)):
        if decimal_list[i] == 0:
            decimal_list.remove(decimal_list[i])

    print(decimal_list)

format_duration(2354678)
```

Comment: Try using nested if.

Comment: If seconds > 3600 is the wrong thing to check. Remember that you've already divided by 60 in the previous step. The best way to check these things is not to just print 'x' inside the `if`. Either use a debugger, or print the parts of the condition before the statement so you can see what is happening

Comment: ^^^  you will benefit greatly from using a debugger.  Try adding the line `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` where you want to examine the code; type `h` to see your options.

Comment: I'm so dumb. I just set another variable that equals to seconds, and then i changed all the seconds in the if statements to the other variable so that it doesn't get divided, and it worked thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added some simple tracing to your code:

```
if seconds >= 60:
    print("TRACE seconds > 60", seconds)
    minute_decimal = seconds % 60
    seconds -= minute_decimal
    seconds /= 60

    decimal_list.append(int(minute_decimal))

    if minute_decimal > 1:
        minute_txt = "minutes"

    else:
        minute_txt = "minute"

print("TRACE minutes were coverted", minute_decimal, seconds)

if seconds >= 3600:
    print("TRACE seconds > 3600", seconds)
```

Output:

```
TRACE seconds > 60
 39244.0
TRACE minutes were coverted 4.0 654.0
[38, 4]
```

Your problem with habits is that you call a *lot* of different values by the name `seconds` throughout your program; I think that you've confused them.  Most notably, the lines

```
    minute_decimal = seconds % 60
    seconds -= minute_decimal
    seconds /= 60
```

extract the sub-minute seconds from the full value, assign that to the variable `minute_decimal`, and then convert the remainder to minutes ... which you then continue to call `seconds`, and test it as such.

You wrote a lot of code without testing much of it.  Put in some useful `print` statements, trace each section as you write it, and don't go on until you've debugged that part.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice that I was dividing seconds every time it goes into an if statement. What I did was making another variable equal to seconds so that it doesn't get divided. I'm quite new to programming. Sorry for the hussle. Thanks for the answer.